# way to join AVI chunks with directshow or other?

Tags: join, append, directshow, avi, cut

I'm trying to re-join smaller chunks of an (one original) AVI file. How can that be done ? I'm programming C++ and been using directshow so far but it seems there's no filter available to achieve what I want. Something like an AVI Append filter or so would be great!

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard merging filter, you will need to write your own or look for third party solution. To write your own you will need to make sure media types match on both sources, and update time stamps on them to stitch the parts together into single smooth stream.

Comment: this answer is helpful in the respect of not having to look for a particular directshow filter anymore. However, I don't know how to program such a filter on my own. Don't know of any third party filter either. I'm trying to use VFW CreateEditedStream for accomplishing it but I get stuck at the moment I want to paste streams (computer crashed at that point). Btw, I only want to combine audio streams (for example two avi files containing only an audio stream each).

Comment: By the way, there is [DES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375458%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to possibly help you with the task, but if I were to choose, I would write a merging filter.

Comment: okay, I've researched DES and how to build filters. DES doesn't provide an example for combining AVIs (at least not in C++, DESCombine is C# /.Net) and building my own filter would take ages... Anyways, can't I simply use the AVI splitter + IMediaSeeking? It works fine for just one cut. It's just that I don't get it to seek to different segments in a row in order to save them to the file. It would always take only the last segment. So, do you think it's possible that way?

Comment: It's easier to cut/trim, it's harder to merge. Because to merge you need two sources and serialization. It is not that difficult, but it's not a basic operation either, and hence no standard filter for that. It's hard to tell what to do if not writing customer filter. Maybe you would instead prefer using AVI API directly.

Comment: to trim would suffice for my application, but it needs to be a multiple trim. I succeeded in cutting the orginal AVI (containing only audio stream) ONCE. But I want to trim it multiple times, preferably using the AVI splitter and IMediaSeeking because that's how it works if I only cut once. So there would be no need to merge but only to cut the relevant pieces and reattach them on-the-fly so to speak. Therefre I've tried calling IMediaSeeking two times (for the beginning) but the RenderStream (with Avi Mux) method only applies the last of the two seeks, the first one is ''ignored''.

Comment: if by AVI API you mean the AVIFile functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd756804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ), I've tried the EditStream functions (as mentioned above), unfotunately I either got stuck at the EditStreamPaste or the AVISave command. I'll give that another try though, maybe it's going to work somehow...

Comment: I meant `AVIFileRead*`/`AVIFileWrite*` that you can sequentially read from N files and copy data into single file, thus trimming source and merging into joint output. AVI only, but it sounds OK for you.

Comment: you mean AVIStreamRead/ AVIStreamWrite, right? That's what I'm currently testing. Meanwhile I've got a little success. Two avi files (audio only and 160 kB/ 253 kB) merge to one file (285 kB) which has the correct time length (2 + 4 = 6 sec.) but cannot be played. Obviously the size should be bigger (413 kB), so I guess the data in the buffer isn't right. So far no idea why. I'm reading from file A and writing the stream from file B to file A. The write function returns 0, so writing is okay. Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: btw, it seems that within the merged file, file A is fully saved (160 kB) and the attached stream corresponds to 125 kB which is the size I get from the AVIStreamRead function for the 2nd file. The bit rates (as shown in Windows Explorer) differ also: data rate says 6kBit/s and total bit rate is at 262 kBit/s for the merged file whereas file B for example has 263 kBit/s data rate and 519 kBit/s total bit rate.